# Is Constrained Language mode enabled by Default?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, security-policy

Is Constrained Language mode enabled in Powershell by default? in latest Windows 10 FCU build, up-to-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also control this via __PSLockdownPolicy env variable. A value of 0 will result in FullLanguage and value of 4 will shift it to ConstrainedLanguage.

Comment: Is it by default or only session/ when run?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can place a PowerShell session into Constrained Language mode simply by setting a property:

```
PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
FullLanguage

PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = "ConstrainedLanguage"

PS C:\> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
ConstrainedLanguage


PS C:\> [System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")

Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Console]::WriteLine("Hello")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage
```

For more details, read this official document:
What is PowerShell Constrained Language?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/11/02/powershell-constrained-language-mode/

Comment: if it's already in ConstraingedLanguage mode, it can't be set to FullLanguage with this method